# Exclude a Customer Customer Segment

Tags: intershop

Currently in Intershop we can assign a promotion, an include, a payment method...etc to one or more customer segments. I would like to do the opposite, i.e. exclude one or more customer segments from a promotion or an include or a payment method...etc. What do you suggest ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry. But that is impossible to achieve. You could try to fiddle with the Prefix pipeline of your application. No guarantee that this will work out.